Azure CI / CD pipeline for legacy ASP.NET Web Forms application
I have an ASP .net webform project that does not have a .sln and .csproj files. so i stuck at the step when create pipeline in azure. where we need to specify the routes for these two file typically
could anyone provide some details how to write the yaml file for such project?
I Have tried various methods , just out of hand now

These are required to understand the dependency and project structure. Without these, there is no straightforward way to know what to build.

Can you create a project yourself and bring in the rest of the files that you already have?

You are not giving enough information, as to what exactly the problem was. However, if you're looking for a way to capture .sln and .csproj files, the expression **\*.csproj and **\*.sln should cover any and all related files within the working repository.
